# Install mvc2 on a server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm on the microsoft download center to download mvc2.

But here I see three links and I have doubts what is what I need:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en#Requirements

- release notes
- MV2 for visual studio 2008
- A test project of MVC2

From which place i could download MVC2 to execute on my server? I dont have there any Visual Studio, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply deploy `System.Web.Mvc.dll` along with your project.
You don't need to install anything on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do it, is use Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). It handles the deployment for you, and can be run straight from IIS.